# How to enable HTML in Laravel Mailable

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to send HTML formatted text to email in Laravel using the mailable feature. When the data is sent, It contains HTML Tags.

**Example**

`Order description    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply <b> dummy text</b> of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>`

**Instead of:**

`Order description    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s`

**sendMail.php**

```php
public function build()
{
    return $this->from('support@example.com')
        ->to('support@example.com')
        ->subject('Premium Article Writers') 
        ->view('invoice')
        ->text('invoice')
        ->with('data',$this->data);
}
```

**Controller**

```php
$data = [
    'description' => $request->description,
];
                       
Mail::to($sender)->send(new SendMail($data));
```

**invoice.blade.php**

```
{!! $data['description'] !!}
```

Comment: Why are your HTML and plain text views the same? What is in the view?

Comment: @miken32 {!! $data['description'] !!}

Comment: Well what's in `$request->description`?

Comment: @miken32 Description Data passed from the form to the controller

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line `->text('invoice')` this sends in text format. By default it's HTML.

Comment: I started with `->view('invoice')` only, but it was not working then I added this `->text('invoice')` still not working

Comment: Check in the header of email you are receiving (in raw format). Is the below header set. 
Content-type:text/html
If it is sent then maybe your email client settings is overriding it.